# ddply 'drop=FALSE' equivalent in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

When using `ddply` to return a dataframe of summary data like so:

```
new_data <- ddply(data, .(grp1, grp2), function(x){
   val_list <- some_func(x.some_val)
   data.frame(
   val_1 = val_list[1],
   val_2 = val_list[2],
   val_3 = val_list[3]
   )}, .drop=FALSE
)
```

The `.drop=FALSE` means I get rows for combinations of `grp1` and `grp2` even if those combinations aren't present in `data`.

What I am looking for is an equivalent functionality in `data.table` when making summary tables using `dt[,.(val1=some_func(some_val1, some_val2)), by='grp1,grp2']` as this will exclude combinations which aren't present.

**EDIT:** More complete example

Input:

```
data = read.csv(text = "
grp1, grp2, some_var1, some_var2
a, x, 3, 1
a, y, 3, 2
a, y, 3, 2
b, x, 3, 2
b, y, 4, 2
b, y, 4, 1 
c, x, 5, 1
c, y, 5, 2 
c, z, 5, 2")
```

Now lets assume I want the mean of (some_var1 * some_var2) for each group as well as the total sum of each var.

If I use ddply:

```
library(plyr)
new_data <- ddply(data, .(grp1, grp2), function(x){
   data.frame(
   val_1 = mean(x$some_var1 * x$some_var2),
   val_2 = sum(x$some_var1),
   val_3 = sum(x$some_var2)
   )}, .drop=FALSE
)
```

Output:

```
grp1, grp2, val_1, val_2, val_3
a, x, 3, 3, 1
a, y, 6, 6, 4
a, z, NA, NA, NA
b, x, 6, 3, 2
b, y, 6, 8, 3
b, z, NA, NA, NA
c, x, 5, 5, 1
c, y, 10, 5, 2
c, z, 10, 5, 2
```

But using `data.table` those `NA` rows would not get included, because the original data does not have those combinations of `grp1` and `grp2`. 
Obviously this is a massively simplified example, in reality I am computing this across many more possible groups, using three grouping variables, and returning more than three new simple summary variables.

Comment: I think it would be useful to give an example data frame and your desired output

Comment: @KenS. More example added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `ddply` approach you mentioned may actually be your best option here. I came up with another solution, but I'd prefer `ddply`, to be honest..

Here we go:

```
f <- function(x, y) {list( mean(x * y), sum(x), sum(y))}

dt[, c("v1", "v2", "v3") := f(some_var1, some_var2), by = list(grp1, grp2)]
dt[, c("some_var1", "some_var2") := NULL]
```

Now, we would imitate the `.drop=FALSE`-functionality by doing a left join, using `merge()`. The trick here, is that we construct a left table using `grid::expand.grid` which contains all combinations of `grp1` and `grp2`:

```
left_tab <- grid::expand.grid(grp1 = unique(dt$grp1), grp2 = unique(dt$grp2))
merge(left_tab, unique(dt), all.x = TRUE)
#       grp1 grp2 val_1 val_2 val_3
# 1    a    x     3     3     1
# 2    a    y     6     6     4
# 3    a    z    NA    NA    NA
# 4    b    x     6     3     2
# 5    b    y     6     8     3
# 6    b    z    NA    NA    NA
# 7    c    x     5     5     1
# 8    c    y    10     5     2
# 9    c    z    10     5     2
```

Comment: Hmm yeah, this seems more complex than `ddply`, especially since my `f` function would have to return much more complex calculations in reality. I was really hoping to benefit from speed increase by using `data.table` but I guess I'll stick with `ddply` in the short term and possibly benchmark your proposed workaround at some point in the future.